# How to exclude fragments when selecting basic activity?

Tags: android-studio

When creating a new project in android studio, I select basic activity but it keeps creating fragments by default as well...is there a way to opt out of that? I know i can delete them but it would be ideal to just exclude them upon project creation!

[image: basic activity]

[image: fragments]

I am targeting min SDK `API 21`, using `Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 patch 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the `Empty activity` option in Android studio dialog. In this case, only activity without any fragments will be created.

[image]

Comment: but i want Floating Action Button thats why i select basic activity

Comment: It seems there is no template in android studio to create an activity without fragments but with FAB :(

Comment: why does google do this :( if they really want to introduce fragments, either upgrade the damn codelabs or create a separate basic activity like v2 or something with their fragments...smh

Comment: @Cataster, Why do you use basic activity for a floating button? Just add the `Floating Button` manually in your `Empty Activity`

Comment: @MDev convenience